# Generic Intersection Code Generation

Tags: algorithm, geometry, collision, intersection

Writing code to test if two shapes (assume 3D) intersect is very error-prone task. I know that there's GJK algorithm, which takes any mathematical definition (support function) of convex shapes and tests intersection of them in generic way.

However, generic test like GJK is slow, compared to handcrafted code containing minimum amount of tests, which are manually proven to be sufficient.

Is there any research (or working code) to generate optimized intersection test code, given parametric definition of shapes?

Example Input(box):
f(a,b,c)(x,y,z) = |x| < a && |y| < b && |z| < c

Example Output:
Generates function that takes (a,b,c) and check intersection against another shape described in a similar way

Comment: What do you mean by parametric definition? I think there are optimized algorithms for cubes, spheres, cylinders, but not much else.

Comment: Added input & output examples. I know this is a very difficult problem, and full solution to this requires automated reasoning in computational geometry.

Comment: No. Why generate code here? There is code already handwritten for all the easy cases. You just need to recognize those cases and dispatch on them.

Comment: The question is mainly theoretical. (but I still see practical value for slightly complex but common shapes like extruded sphere, cusuple, box etc. which is often too complex for manual derivation)